# Is IIS Authentication different from ASP.NET Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I know about ASP.NET Authentication mode (Form, Windows and Passport) and we have used mostly Form based authentication for our web applications. I want to know how IIS takes part in authentication, does it pre-authenticates the request before passing it to the ASP.NET. How can I configure IIS authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

Very broad topic, but essentially, IIS does not authenticate if anonymous authentication is enabled. This relies on the application to do any required authentication (such as Forms, as you mentioned)

If anonymous is turned off, IIS can authenticate using the following methods:

- Basic: credentials passed as http header with each request
- Digest: sort of a more-secure basic; the password is hashed
- Windows: uses client's windows credentials to authenticate
- Certificate: requires a specific x509 certificate to be sent by the client

More details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: ok that was useful, as from the above methods of authentication through IIS, it seems IIS does handles authentication differently from the ASP.NET. Also, from the link you provided it says IIS has 2 authentication methods challenge based and login redirection method, where challenge based authenticates using Windows credentials and login redirection based redirects to login form where in my opinion ASP.NET should (if has) handle authentication. Pls, correct me if I am wrong.